# C# WPF - how to move a comboxbox over a datagrid cell programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, controls, move

I use WPF with C#

I have a DataGrid in which I need to display a combobox.
I know that I can do this by adding a DataGridComboBoxColumn to the DataGrid but then I have comboboxes for each cell in that column.

But what I need to do is to display a Combox only for certain cells in a column.
So what I have tried is to display a Combobox (cboSelectToleranz) over the current datagrid cell by using Cell.PointToScreen() and TranslateTransform() to move a Combobox to the position of the clicked cell:

So here is what I have tried (Code behind) but it doesn't work (the Combobox disappears from screen...)

```
private void myDatagrid_onCurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!displayCombobox)  return;


    //get screen postion of cell that was clicked
    //
    var cellContent = myDatagrid.CurrentCell.Column.GetCellContent(myDatagrid.CurrentCell.Item);
    DataGridCell cell = cellContent.Parent as DataGridCell;
    Point Position = cell.PointToScreen(new Point(0, 0));


    //try to move a combobox over current cell 
    //
    var tt = new TranslateTransform();

    tt.X = Position.X; 
    tt.Y = Position.Y;

    cboSelectToleranz.RenderTransform = tt;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netframework-4.8) along with [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8). Define your templates, one of which will be `ComboBox`.

`DataTemplateSelector` will choose proper template depending on the value of binded property:

```cs
// example of custom type and simple DataTemplateSelector
public class YourItemType
{ 
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public class YourTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TextTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ComboTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return (item is YourItemType yourItem && yourItem.Property.Equals("condition here")) ? ComboTemplate : TextTemplate;
    }
}
```

```xml
<!--Somewhere in static resources-->
<DataTemplate x:Key="comboTemplate">
    <ComboBox IsEditable='False'
              ItemsSource='{Binding YourItemsSource}' SelectedItem='{Binding Property}'
              Text='{Binding Property}' />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="textTemplate">
    <ComboBox Text='{Binding Property}' />
</DataTemplate>

<local:YourTemplateSelector x:Key='YourTemplateSelector'
                            TextTemplate='{StaticResource textTemplate}'
                            ComboTemplate='{StaticResource comboTemplate}' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the DataGridTemplateColumn.

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn?view=netframework-4.8

Into the datatemplate, you can define the ComboBox and bind his visibility to a property of your model.